# How to do validation on duplicate records when reading an excel file

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, validation

I can read the data from excel file based on the current code. Just i have no idea how to do validating when there is a duplicate record found in excel. Need a guidance from expert, any help would be appreciated !

### record in excel file

SEQNO | UNIT NO  |  NAME  |  NAME 2 | BANK_CODE | BANK_REF_NO
 1           | A2-1-1     |   ALI    | ABU        | 123456789      |  999999999
 2           | A2-1-1     |   AKI    | ABA        | 222222222      |  888888888

### JSP

```
       <%     
        vTable = new Vector();

        Vector vGetExcel=ReadXLSXFile.importExcelSheet(upload_path+"//"+ATTACH_FILE);
        for (int i=0;i<vGetExcel.size();i++){

        Vector vTableRow = (Vector)vGetExcel.elementAt(i);

        if(vTableRow.size()>=4)
        {

            String sSEQ_NO          = (String) vTableRow.elementAt(0);
            String sUNIT_NO         = (String) vTableRow.elementAt(1);
            String sOWNER_NAME      = (String) vTableRow.elementAt(2);
            String sOWNER_NAME2     = (String) vTableRow.elementAt(3);
            String sMORTGAGEE_NAME  = (String) vTableRow.elementAt(4);
            String sBANK_REF        = (String) vTableRow.elementAt(5);
            intSeqNo                = vTable.size();

            if(sUNIT_NO.equals(""))
            {
                break;
            }

            if(!sOWNER_NAME.equals(""))
            {
                intSeqNo   += 1;
                SERIAL      = df.format(intSeqNo);

                Vector vRecord  = new Vector();
                vRecord.addElement(Integer.toString(i+1));
                vRecord.addElement(Integer.toString(i+1));
                vRecord.addElement(sUNIT_NO);
                vRecord.addElement(sOWNER_NAME.toUpperCase());
                vRecord.addElement(sOWNER_NAME2.toUpperCase());
                vRecord.addElement(sMORTGAGEE_NAME.toUpperCase());
                vRecord.addElement(sBANK_REF);
                vRecord.addElement(SERIAL);
                vTable.addElement(vRecord);
            }               
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        } %>
```

### ReadXLSXFile.java

```
public Vector importExcelSheet(String fileName)
{
    Vector cellVectorHolder = new Vector();
    try
    {
        Workbook workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator rowIter = sheet.rowIterator();

        while(rowIter.hasNext())
        {
            XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rowIter.next();
            Iterator cellIter = row.cellIterator();
            Vector cellStoreVector=new Vector();

            while(cellIter.hasNext())
            {
                XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                cellStoreVector.addElement(cell+"");
            }
            cellVectorHolder.addElement(cellStoreVector);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return cellVectorHolder;
}
```

Expected result : when read the file from excel, if there is a duplicate record found then break.

Comment: what column is duplicated.  Simply have a variable to keep the last value and check the current value against this.  Also please do not use JSP for java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
ArrayList lastUnitNo = new ArrayList ();
for (int i=0;i<vGetExcel.size();i++){

    Vector vTableRow = (Vector)vGetExcel.elementAt(i);

    if(vTableRow.size()>=4)
    {

        String sSEQ_NO          = (String) vTableRow.elementAt(0);
        String sUNIT_NO         = (String) vTableRow.elementAt(1);
        String sOWNER_NAME      = (String) vTableRow.elementAt(2);
        String sOWNER_NAME2     = (String) vTableRow.elementAt(3);
        String sMORTGAGEE_NAME  = (String) vTableRow.elementAt(4);
        String sBANK_REF        = (String) vTableRow.elementAt(5);
        intSeqNo                = vTable.size();

        if (lastUnitNo.contains(sUNIT_NO) {
            break;
        }
        lastUnitNo.add (sUNIT_NO);

        ....
  }
```

Comment: Not working.. if the duplicate records are in inorder sequence. example `A2-1-1, A2-1-2 , A2-1-3 , A2-1-4 , A2-1-1 , A2-1-1 , A2-1-1 ` it result as `A2-1-1, A2-1-2, A2-1-3 , A2-1-4, A2-1-1` the rest break.